# Brandenburger-Keisler paradox

Tags: logic, game-theory, paradoxes

The Brandenburger-Keisler paradox runs as follows.

1) Suppose that *A believes that B assumes that A believes that B's assumption is wrong*

2) Ask whether A believes that B's assumption is wrong

3.1) If A believes that B's assumption is wrong, then in A's view B's assumption is right. But then A believes that B's assumption is right. Contradiction.

3.2) If A believes that B's assumption is right, then in A's view B's assumption is wrong. But then A believes that B's assumption is wrong. Contradiction.

Now, there is something I cannot clear about all this.

a) As it stands, it runs as well if we replace 2) with *Ask whether A believes that B's assumption is right*, doesn't it?

b) Suppose that A believes that B's assumption is wrong/right. Then, shouldn't B's assumption be, so to say, objectively right/wrong, not only *in A's view*?

c) Be it as it may, why should we conclude from A believing that B's assumption is wrong/right, and from B's assumption being right/wrong, that A also believes that B's assumption is right/wrong? I mean, A believes that B's assumption is wrong/right, and depending on that B's assumption will be right/wrong respectively, but why such a belief should then be ascribed to A?

d) Couldn't we say: suppose that A believes that B's assumption is wrong. Then A believes that A believes that B's assumption is right. We assume that *A believes that A believes that p* is tantamount to *A believes that p*, and then we get that A believes that B's assumption is right.

Comment: You might find this useful https://pacuit.org/static/bkparadox_sl-4ecb482dfeed0bd4afdf28eafe61e6ec.pdf.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. But still can't get why, if Ann believes that Bob's assumption is wrong, since Bob assumption is right, Ann believe this too (whence the contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

Brandenburger-Keisler Paradox:

> "A believes B assumes^1 that A believes B's assumption^1 is wrong".

a) Yes.

b) No, beliefs are not equivalent to objective truths. In fact, I suppose the only thing "objective" used in deriving a contradiction from this paradox is the law of excluded middle.

c) You're right and this is the point that allows us to conclude that the BK-paradox *is* a paradox. Another point of view: We want to know if the BK-paradox is consistent, i.e. we are trying to see if anyone, taking the place of $A$, can hold the belief of the BK-paradox *without* running into a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, the one to point c) is not very clear to me. At the moment, I figure out the situation as follows. Suppose a dialogue like: "ehy A, do you believe B's assumption is wrong?", "Yes, I do", "And what's B's assumption in your opinion?", "That I believe that his assumption is wrong", "But then B's assumption is right afterall", "Yes indeed", "And what's B's assumption in your opinion?", "That I believe that this assumption is wrong", "But then B's assumption is wrong afterall", "Yes indeed", and so on.

More on next comment!

Comment: Just another remark. Informally, the paradox runs also if we replace "B assumes" with "B believes". There, I think, it depends on how "belief" and "assumption" are understood. I think, but I may be wrong (I've read something meanwhile), that "belief" involves an existential quantification, whereas "assumption" a universal one. So, with belief it would run like "in some of the worlds accessible to A some of the worlds accessible to B are such that in some of the worlds accessible to A what is in some of the worlds accessible to B is false". So, here the paradox may not go through. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the dialogue? I'm not sure the paradox runs on definitions of "beliefs" and "assumptions" as much as the concept of self-reference. In my answer, I write '^1' to indicate what "B's assumption" is referring to. In fact, what if I said "A knows B knows^1 that A knows B's knowledge^1 is wrong" where knowledge is referring to that "B knows^1 that A knows B's knowledge^1 is wrong"? We would similarly derive a contradiction.

Comment: Yes indeed that's what I say. The paradox seems to me to go through also if we say "A believes that B believes that A believes that B belief is wrong". But then why it is formulated with assumption, instead of belief? As for the dialogue, that's how I represent the paradoxical situation. A alternatively believes that B's assumption is right and wrong.